# JavaScript function inside Event Queue doesn't move to Call Stack as expected

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I created two JS programs to test out the nature of JavaScript call stack, event queue and Timer request handler async API.

Scenario #1.

```js
function logFirst(){
 console.log('First');
}

function logThird() {
 for (var i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
  if (i == 999999999) {
   console.log("Third");
  }
 }
}

logFirst(); //first sync function

setTimeout(function() {
 console.log('Second');
}, 0);

logThird(); //painfully slow sync function called
```

This program executes First, then moves on to encounter setTimeout, which is an async task. Since this task is async, it is handled by the browser's Timer Handler API, which executes a timer for 0 seconds, and then enqueues the anonymous callback function passed to setTimeout inside the event queue of the browser.

But until all of this happens, the third function, a blocking peice of code logThird() has already been called. The call stack is busy since the iteration takes a substantial amount of time to complete. On the last iteration, "Third" is printed to the console.

When logThird() is done executing the call stack becomes free, and the callback that was in the event queue is now pushed to the call stack, and it executes.

Scenario #2.
I created two functions of the blocking kind, like so:

```js
function logFirst(){
 console.log('First');
}

function logThird() {
 for (var i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
  if (i == 999999999) {
   console.log("Third");
  }
 }
}

function logFourth() {
 for (var i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
  if (i == 999999999) {
   console.log("Fourth");
  }
 }
}

logFirst(); //first sync function
setTimeout(function() { // an async task
 console.log('Second');
}, 0);
logThird();  //painfully slow sync function called

//isn't the call stack free at this point in time?

logFourth(); //another painfully slow sync function called
```

Then I ran this code under the assumption that the call stack would be empty after logThird has finished executing and before logFourth has been pushed to the call stack. So "Second" should have been printed third. But it was printed last.

(Please run both snippets in fullscreen mode to be able to see the JS console output)

Why didn't the async callback get pushed into the call stack?

Comment: _"Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers) are only run when there’s been an opening in the execution."_- from this post - http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: What makes you think the call stack is empty after `logThird` - you're still in a block of code running your script, are you not?

Comment: @JamesThorpe But the script is not a function itself is it? Call stack is just for single instructions, or functions, is it not?

Comment: @Craicerjack I understand that line. My premise for the question is that _there is_ an opening in the execution, between the execution of `LogThird()` function and that of `LogFourth()` function, in the second snippet.

Comment: But on that same premise, as soon as `setTimeout` returns, there would be an opening on the call stack, and the timeout should run immediately before `logThird` runs in either case.  You're only considering stack frames created when explicitly calling functions, but ignoring the initial stack frame that's created to run the entire script.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Okay! I didn't know that the entire JavaScript file would run at the bottom of the stack. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

> The call stack would be empty after logThird has finished executing and before logFourth has been pushed to the call stack

No, there still is the global execution context (stack frame) that runs your script and actually pushes `logFourth` on the stack by calling it. If there wasn't such a thing (which, admittedly, is not a *function* execution context), every statement of the script would have to go through the event loop itself.

Comment: I didn't know of the global execution context at all. Thank you for clearing that up!